# Random log off without any warning

Tags: linux, debian, drivers

I have a netbook with Debian 8 (before kali, and before that, ubuntu) And i got a weird problem (with all them): even without xserver running, its log off randomly without any warning.

dmesg doesn't show anything weird. The weirdest thing it's if I connect an external screen through VGA, the problem stops; but if I disconnect the screen, the problem starts again.

I've already reinstalled intel drivers, and there's no xorg.conf file in X11 directory.

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` for possible hints.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Apparently, it was a driver problem. 
I executed

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

with the VGA cable connected.